# <input type='file'> Remove gallery option from list (FOR MOBILE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I want to restrict the user to upload image or video only by camera and not through gallery or file manager. Is there any option to do it with below code or any other option to do it?

```
<input id="video-selector" type="file" name="files[]" accept="video/*,image/*" capture="camera" >
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No expert here, but maybe this can help: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: Thanks @peter but that didn't helped